# How can I assign a specific maven profile to an intellij run configuration?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-profiles

I have multiple projects loaded into my project structure and they all use different maven profiles.  I know I can switch up the profiles using the Maven Projects tab but I would like to assign a specific profile to go along with a specific run configuration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can assign specific profiles via the dialog "Edit Run Configurations". See this screenshot:

[image]

AFAIK, this profile setting overrides the choice which you select in the maven view of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 42):

If You have created maven profiles in your `pom.xml`, you should be able to see the profiles in right side of Intellij Idea

[image: You can select this profile]

If there will be multiple profile you can activate one by default

```
           <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
```

Or for running specific profile we can select `mvn install -Pbuild-profile`

Comment: This window can be found from menus View | Tool Windows | Maven Projects